# Cropped image not saving - ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on `ruby 2.3.1` and `rails 3.2.13` in a crop feature. I am using a cropper.js JavaScript library for cropping the image and adding the cropped image to the input field for saving in server. Cropping is working fine but the cropped image not getting saved.

brand.rb

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :inverse_of => :brands
  mount_uploader :image, AwsBrandImageUploader
end
```

crop_popup.haml

```
:javascript
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#cropperImage').cropper({
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      crop: function(dataNew) {
        // Output the result data for cropping image.        
      }
    });    
  });

  function cropBrandImage() {
    var croppedImage = $('#cropperImage').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    $('#image').attr('src', croppedImage);
    $('[name="brand[image]"]').val(croppedImage); //add the cropped image to the input field using field name
  }
```

_form.haml before crop feature:

```
  .span6{:style=>"margin-left:60px"}
    = f.label :image, label: '<span title="For best results upload an image with an aspect ration of 3 (wide) by 2 (high)."><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Brand image</span>'
    %div{style: 'width:201px;height:134px;border:3px solid #EEEEEE;background:#EEEEEE;', class: 'image_preview text-center'}
      - if @brand.image?
        = image_tag @brand.image_url(:mobile400), style: 'max-width:201px;max-height:134px;', id: 'image'
      - else
        %img(src='/assets/default_produce_image.jpg'){style: 'max-width:201px;max-height:134px;', id: 'image'}
      = hidden_field(:image, :field, :value => @brand.image)
    %div{:style => 'margin-top:15px;'}
      = f.file_field :image, :class => 'filestyle', :onchange => 'imagePreview(this, "image", false)'
    %span{:id => 'error_image'}
```

_form.haml after crop feature implemented:

```
  .span6{:style=>"margin-left:60px"}
    = f.label :image, label: '<span title="For best results upload an image with an aspect ration of 3 (wide) by 2 (high)."><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Brand image</span>'
    %div{style: 'width:201px;height:134px;border:3px solid #EEEEEE;background:#EEEEEE;', class: 'image_preview text-center'}
      - if @brand.image?
        = image_tag @brand.image_url(:mobile400), style: 'max-width:201px;max-height:134px;', id: 'image'
      - else
        %img(src='/assets/default_produce_image.jpg'){style: 'max-width:201px;max-height:134px;', id: 'image'}
      = f.hidden_field(:image, :value => @brand.image)
    %span{:id => 'error_image'}
```

I am using `CarrierWave::MiniMagick` for uploading and saving the image file.I am doing the form post for saving the data. When i upload the image using file field and clicking save is saving the image in server. But when i crop the same image through the crop_popup and then click save is not saving the image.

I am cropping the image in a popup and adding the cropped image to the input field using field name. Also i have added the .haml file change before and after crop implementation.

Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console? Also, I don't see you calling your `cropBrandImage()` function anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help some one with minimum search time,

This is suitable for who use carrierwave for image upload. CarrierWave will not accept `base64` directly and instead it expect the `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` instance of image. Since the cropped image is base64, we have to explicitly convert the `base64` to `ActionDispatch` instance.

base64_to_action_dispatch_decoder.rb

```
class ImageDecoder

  def self.parse_image_data(base64_image)
    filename = "cropped-image"
    in_content_type, encoding, string = base64_image.split(/[:;,]/)[1..3]

    @tempfile = Tempfile.new(filename)
    @tempfile.binmode
    @tempfile.write Base64.decode64(string)
    @tempfile.rewind

    # for security we want the actual content type, not just what was passed in
    content_type = `file --mime -b #{@tempfile.path}`.split(";")[0]

    # we will also add the extension ourselves based on the above
    # if it's not gif/jpeg/png, it will fail the validation in the upload model
    extension = content_type.match(/gif|jpeg|png/).to_s
    filename += ".#{extension}" if extension

    ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
        tempfile: @tempfile,
        content_type: content_type,
        filename: filename
      })
  end

end
```

Original source is from https://gist.github.com/ifightcrime/9291167a0a4367bb55a2.

Decode the format before create/update like below,

```
if params[:some_params][:image].include? "base64"
  params[:some_params] ||= {}
  params[:some_params][:image] = ImageDecoder.parse_image_data(params[:some_params][:image])
end
```